# The Towers of Hanoi

Tags: java, recursion

Im trying to figure out why my code for the Hanoi recursion isnt working :/

```
 public class Hanoiprog extends Thread
{
    private Hanoi hanoi;

    public Hanoiprog(Hanoi hanoi)
    {
        this.hanoi = hanoi;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        playHanoi(hanoi.getdisks(), 0, 1, 2);
    }

    public void playHanoi(int disks, int from, int to, int temp)
    {
        if (disks == 1){
            hanoi.move(0, 1);
        } else{
            playHanoi(disks - 1, from, temp, to);
            hanoi.move(0, 2);
            playHanoi(disks - 1, temp, to, from);



        }

    }
```

I dont get why this isn´t working. It´s really all about this code. The rest of my classes is perfectly fine. The Towers have the indices 0,1,2. Hope you can help me

I know there is ALOT of answers in the Internet, but actually there is the same code everytime and its similar to mine. But it doesnt seem to work ?!

Comment: How is it not working? We need more information.

Comment: with all that code I cannot figure how it is not working also, well I can, but please, provide more information, we do this for free, so please, dont haggle with code

Comment: Please provide your complete solution.

Comment: what are "from", "to" and "temp"? We miss information here.

Comment: Why not just compare it to one of the tousand complete code examples doing exactly this school task?

Comment: Its dificult, because there are alot of classes for a grafic surface and stuff. 

It is pretty much just moving the first disk from A to B (which i dont understand) and then moving the 2nd disk from A to C ... this is fine for me, but now its NOT moving the 1st disk from B to C. Its trying to move the 3rd disk from A to C, but it cant cause it cant move a bigger disk on a smaller one.

Comment: from, to and temp are the towers (indices 0,1,2) ... the disks are starting at the Tower "from" (index 0) and i want them to get to Tower "to" (index 1) ... temp is some kind of workspace to get it done

Comment: I compared my code with all the others in the internet and its pretty much the same. I just hoped maybe someone here is getting what i aint get.

Comment: @user3002086 Compare your solution to my posted answer.

Comment: Sorry, I did, but i dont get where the difference is :(

Answer (score 0):

```
FUNCTION MoveTower(disk, source, dest, spare):
IF disk == 0, THEN:
    move disk from source to dest
ELSE:
    MoveTower(disk - 1, source, spare, dest)   // Step 1 above
    move disk from source to dest              // Step 2 above
    MoveTower(disk - 1, spare, dest, source)   // Step 3 above
END IF
```

**Source:** http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cburch/survey/recurse/hanoiimpl.html

Comment: Why the downvote? The OP can compare and see easily there problem.

Comment: Isn´t this pretty much the same? I found this code in the internet, aswell, but mine isnt working for a reason ...

Comment: @user3002086 Edit your original question to include all your code.

Comment: @user3002086 Does it work without using `Threads`?

Comment: I did ... but u can be sure that everything else is correct. Its really all about this piece of code which is not working the right way. Actually i think theres something wront with

playHanoi(disks - 1, temp, to, from);

its not really swaping them ... or i dont know. Im pretty much of a beginner. Sorry guys

Comment: No it doesnt work without using Threads

Comment: @user3002086 Where do you output your game state? `void` means that method does not return anything

Comment: Its running on a grafic surface. the problem is that i didnt program the rest of the classes, because im just starting with java. Well, it actually should work, because everywhere in the internet i find the same code. I´m pretty sure there is something wrong with 

"playHanoi(disks - 1, temp, to, from);" 

I dont even get why this is necessary, because it´s a recursion isnt it? So in the next step I overwrite that information with 

"playHanoi(disks - 1, from, temp, to);"

Comment: Recursion in this case has: a base state and a smaller state to pass back to itself. Each recursive call it should get smaller. Try `if(disks == 0)` and make the `hanoi.move(0, 2);` 0,1. Without seeing the full picture it is very hard

Comment: ya, I understand that. Well its everytime the same. It is moving the first one from A to B (which is alright). The 2nd one from A to C (which is alright). Then its tryin to move the 3rd one from A to C / A to B (im not sure) ... and it cant do that, because its not supposed to put a bigger disk on a smaller one. I want it to move the 1st one from B to C.

Comment: If I change "(disks == 0)" and "hanoi.move(0,2);" it is moving the first disk from A to C, which i don´t understand, because i start the method with 5 disks. Why isnt it immediately using the "else" part?! There might be my problem. It should ignore the first part cause the number of disks isnt == 1. But it doesnt ignore it :/

Comment: @user3002086 So now you have found your problem area, you need to create some scenario's and try to see what it is doing wrong. This is called black box testing and these scenarios you are going to make are normally well documented before any coding begins.

Comment: The problem is I pretty much tested the whole day yesterday. Asking for it here is like my last attempt to get a answer. And I just don´t get why its not immediately using the else part :/ But I can understand that it is hard to solve something if u can´t see the whole prog.